# When accessing model object property I get error undefined

Tags: angularjs

When I want to use model like this:

```
console.log($scope.selectedMonth);
```

I get output:

> Object { no: "02", name: "Veljača", $$hashKey: "object:24" }

But when I want to use one of its properties like this:

```
  console.log($scope.selectedMonth.name);
```

I get error:

> Error: $scope.selectedMonth is undefined

Why is that happening and how do I access model object properties?

Comment: What is your Code?

Comment: @ArunShinde No, it's not array of objects.

Comment: Because when you're trying to output `console.log($scope.selectedMonth.name);`, the object is undefined. What more do you want to get with the limited details provided in the question?

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks , this actually gave me hint to fix the problem

Comment: Really? LOL, glad I was able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When object was initialized it was undefined by default. This line of code is inside `$watch` method and I added `if` statement that fixed the problem.

```
  if ($scope.selectedMonth !== undefined) {
    console.log($scope.selectedMonth.name);
  }
```